# how to pass city and country to geocode

Tags: python, geopy

I want to make sure I get the lat and lng for right city. For e.g there is Sydney in Australia and Sydney in Canada. This works fine

```
for d in listofobjs:
    location = geolocator.geocode(d['city'])
    d2 = {
        'username': d['username'],
        'latitude': location.latitude,
        'longitude': location.longitude
    }
    listofobjs2.append(d2)
```

But I get an error if I try location like this instead

```
location = geolocator.geocode(d['city'],d['country'])
```

I get an error when I try to read latitude from locatoion

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Is it possible to pass both city and country to geocode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation it is stated that geolocator.geocode can return 0,1 or more values.
The method can return a list, hence the error message when you try to access it as a single structure element.
Or iterate through the list and append to listofobjs2 as much as needed.

You cannot be sure of getting exactly 1 location match. But why passing 2 parameters? I would combine them in a string like in the docs example:

"some address NYC". So if you put your request like this:

d['city']+" "+d['country']

it would match the example much better

https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/

Comment: You are right, it will return the list. But the list of all the possible location.  [Location(Vancouver, Greater Vancouver Regional District, British Columbia, Canada, (49.2608944, -123.1139382, 0.0)), Location(Vancouver, Clark County, Washington, United States of America, (45.6306954, -122.6744556, 0.0)), Location(Vancouver, Clark County, Washington, United States of America, (45.6306954, -122.6744556, 0.0)), Location(Vancouver, San Antonio del Tequendama, Cundinamarca, Colombia, (4.585473, -74.3518472, 0.0)), ....It would need further processing. no other easier way ?

Comment: In the docs there's this example: location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC"). I don't know geolocator API but I suppose that geolocator.geocode(d['city']+ " " + d['country']) would work (1 string with city + country instead of a 2 parameter call which I cannot match in the documentation)